# Resolving 2 Python version in Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, path, anaconda

I am running **Mac OS X 10.11.5**.
I have two Python versions on my machine:

1. **Python 2.7** (Inbuilt python in OSX) and
2. **Python 3.5** (Anaconda version- 4.1.1)

The path is set up as shown:

> $PATH
>
> -bash: /Users/userNMS/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory

The problem is when I am trying to install few packages like pandas, Theano etc., using anaconda. I get **ERROR: Failure: ImportError** (No Module found)

By default the Python Path points to this one  i.e (Python version- 2.7)

`> whereis python`

```
/usr/bin/python
```

But my actual Path which I want to work is Python 3.5 (Anaconda version):

```
> which python

/Users/userNMS/anaconda/bin/python
```

The Python site packages path is as follows:

```
/Users/userNMS/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

The packages from site-packages ( say pandas, Theano etc., ) is not getting retrieved from the above path, giving away **Import Error**

Please help me on this !! Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to create a new conda enviornment and install your packages there. This will help you avoid any issues if you still want to use 2.7. Example would be:

`conda create --name foo python=3 pandas Theano`